# UITableView insert row at top crashes

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to insert a row at the top of `UITableView`, but it crashes in the last line where I declare the `endUpdating`. This is the code I'm using and I'm using a button outside the table to insert row.

```
[comments insertObject:comment atIndex:0];
[self.commentsTableView beginUpdates];
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.commentsTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.commentsTableView endUpdates]; //here crashes with "assertion failure"
```

I know I can just do insert in array and reload, but I want to do it with animation.
Thank you in advance.

This is my cell for row method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CommentCell";
// Similar to UITableViewCell, but
ListingCommentTableViewCell *cell = (ListingCommentTableViewCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ListingCommentTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.commenterLabel.text = [[comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"user"];
[cell.commenterLabel sizeToFit];
cell.commentLabel.text = [[comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text"];
[cell.commentLabel sizeToFit];
cell.lineView.frame = CGRectMake(5 , cell.commentLabel.frame.origin.y + cell.commentLabel.frame.size.height+ 5, cell.frame.size.width-20, 1);
cell.dateLabel.text = [Utils formatCommentDate:[[comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"createdOn"]];
return cell;
```

}

THis is my cell height method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

int height = [Utils findHeightForText:[[comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"teksti"] havingWidth:screenWidth - 40   andFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu" size:14]];

height += 25;

return height + 5;
}
```

and my number of rows method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [comments count];
}
```

Comment: Is the question about finding out why it crashes, or how to animate it?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: @Student - (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
  you have to pass array

Comment: You add object at last index and after got array in reverse order and add the row at top order.

Comment: Does your data source reflect the change?

Comment: This is the error      *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:1368 , @Neeku the answer to both is the same

Comment: @amar yes I checked with NSLog

Comment: Can we have your cell for row method? i guess you are not handling data source well Double check your data source and do clean derived data

Comment: @Elgert a side note - from iOS 6 onwards you no longer need to check for nil (in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method).

Comment: Didnt know but still i dont think thats the problem

Comment: Which is why I suggested it as a side note :)

Comment: Have you tried updating your data source `comments` after the call to `endUpdates` or as shown by @mohacs during the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I insert objects to UITableView with animation.

```
-(void)updateMethod {
    [self.commentsTableView beginUpdates];
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [comments insertObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:comment, nil] atIndexes:indexSet];
    [self.commentsTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.commentsTableView endUpdates]; 
}
```

You should check `numberOfRowsInSection` and be sure it reflect your `comments.count`

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return comments.count;
}
```

Also all UI updates must be done on the main thread, if you call your update method in different thread there is a change you can see that error.

Comment: Again i get error at `[self.commentsTableView endUpdates];` it says The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (6) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'  its strange because i check the count of my Array and it increases

Comment: Is it your UITableView contains groups?

Comment: you mean sections ?  No just 1  `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}`

Comment: If there is not groups/sections can you try deleting numberOfSectionsInTableView delegate and give another try?

Comment: Weird! You might want to edit your question and add your UITableViewDelegate methods, then we can see more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should update data source array inside animation block:

```
[self.commentsTableView beginUpdates];
[comments insertObject:comment atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.commentsTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.commentsTableView endUpdates];
```